Type-hinting a generator: send_type Any or None?
I have a generator that does not use send() values. Should I type its send_value as Any or None?
import typing as t

def pi_generator() -> t.Generator[int, ???, None]:
    pi = "3141592"
    for digit in pi:
        yield int(digit)

pi_gen = pi_generator()
next(pi_gen)  # 3
pi_gen.send('foo')  # 1
pi_gen.send(pi_gen)  # 4

Reasons I see for Any:

The generator works perfectly fine with send() for any type, so if somebody had a reason to use .send(1) with this generator, it's totally fine.
Methods' arguments' types should be general, and .send(x: Any) is more general than .send(x: None).

Reasons I see for None:

Return types should be specific, and "Generator that never uses send" is a more specific type than "Any kind of generator".
If someone is using .send() to this generator, it's likely they're misunderstanding what it does and the type hint should inform them.


Quoting the docs for typing.Generator:

If your generator will only yield values, set the SendType and ReturnType to None:
def infinite_stream(start: int) -> Generator[int, None, None]:
   while True:
       yield start
       start += 1


Setting SendType to None is the recommended way to communicate that the generator does not expect callees to send() values.

Do you have any hints why not typing.Never instead? I'd say that prohibiting manual .send(None) is better than allowing, but the docs don't even suggest this alternative.

Actually this documentation snippet is older than 3.11 where Never was introduced (and NoReturn wasn't initially meant to have meaning outside of functions with unreachable end, so wasn't considered here), this may be simply an omission. I'll open a documentation ticket tonight to get more input.
